# Place background on top of another at the top center of the container in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a background image on top of another background image and place it at the top center of the container.

Like this. The Stars background is a separate image then the planet.

[image]

At the moment, the planet background is appears on the top left of the container and displacing the text to its bottom edge. I would like to place the text at the middle of the container as it normally would go.

I also need to be responsive, when viewed on smaller screens (not smaller than laptops), the background needs to appear in the same place.

**EDIT** I need the planet image to stay fixed as well because I am going to add a parallax effect to it later on.

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/73p0336p/21/

HTML

```
<section id="third-section">
  <div class="mars">
    <div class="mars_planet"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="text-left">The Launch</h1>
        <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla diam quis turpis eleifend, ac molestie diam consectetur. In at augue tellus. Pellentesque efficitur efficitur nisl, suscipit blandit mauris. Quisque consectetur tincidunt suscipit. Nullam fermentum dictum quam vel volutpat. Phasellus eleifend molestie neque id varius. Aenean convallis ornare nisi vitae blandit. Phasellus imperdiet, diam vel congue blandit, quam felis vehicula tellus, eget lacinia dui quam vel metus. Proin eleifend volutpat magna et convallis. Nam pharetra, orci eu aliquet efficitur, turpis leo consequat purus, sed fringilla metus arcu ac elit.</p>
          <p class="text-left">ALorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla diam quis turpis eleifend, ac molestie diam consectetur. In at augue tellus. Pellentesque efficitur efficitur nisl, suscipit blandit mauris. Quisque consectetur tincidunt suscipit. Nullam fermentum dictum quam vel volutpat. Phasellus eleifend molestie neque id varius. Aenean convallis ornare nisi vitae blandit. Phasellus imperdiet, diam vel congue blandit, quam felis vehicula tellus, eget lacinia dui quam vel metus. Proin eleifend volutpat magna et convallis. Nam pharetra, orci eu aliquet efficitur, turpis leo consequat purus, sed fringilla metus arcu ac elit.</p>
          <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla diam quis turpis eleifend, ac molestie diam consectetur. In at augue tellus. Pellentesque efficitur efficitur nisl, suscipit blandit mauris. Quisque consectetur tincidunt suscipit. Nullam fermentum dictum quam vel volutpat. Phasellus eleifend molestie neque id varius. Aenean convallis ornare nisi vitae blandit. Phasellus imperdiet, diam vel congue blandit, quam felis vehicula tellus, eget lacinia dui quam vel metus. Proin eleifend volutpat magna et convallis. Nam pharetra, orci eu aliquet efficitur, turpis leo consequat purus, sed fringilla metus arcu ac elit.</p>
          <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla diam quis turpis eleifend, ac molestie diam consectetur. In at augue tellus. Pellentesque efficitur efficitur nisl, suscipit blandit mauris. Quisque consectetur tincidunt suscipit. Nullam fermentum dictum quam vel volutpat. Phasellus eleifend molestie neque id varius. Aenean convallis ornare nisi vitae blandit. Phasellus imperdiet, diam vel congue blandit, quam felis vehicula tellus, eget lacinia dui quam vel metus. Proin eleifend volutpat magna et convallis. Nam pharetra, orci eu aliquet efficitur, turpis leo consequat purus, sed fringilla metus arcu ac elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #191617;
}
section {
    padding: 130px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
section::before,
section::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
}

#third-section {
    height: auto;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 3rem;
    color: #dcdcdc;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/XTQJ9Lo.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#third-section h1 {
    font-size: 72px;
    color: #dcdcdc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.mars {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.mars_planet {
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/yQfisM6.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    z-index: 200;
    width: 2364px;
    height: 1563px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -76.3rem 0 0 -1182px;
    will-change: transform;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px) scale(1);
    transition: opacity 4000ms 1500ms cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}
```

Comment: The planet transparent image is so cool. How did you creat that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the planet image into a separate block, you can use multiple backgrounds:

https://jsfiddle.net/73p0336p/30/

```
#third-section {
    ...
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/yQfisM6.png'), url('http://i.imgur.com/XTQJ9Lo.jpg');
    background-position: center top, center top;
    background-size: 100% auto, cover;
    background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

Change the first `background-attachment` value to `scroll` if you want the plant image to scroll with the text.

Comment: The planet image is placed in the center center of the container, I need it to be at the top center (please refer to my original post's screenshot). And yes, I need the planet image to fixed because I'm going to apply a parallax effect to it later on.

Comment: @Halnex, it looks in the center, because it's size is set to `cover` now, which can easily be changed. However, having it as a background image won't allow you to parallax, so please ignore this answer (unless you are OK to parallax by changing the background position, it will work in this case).

Comment: I need to have as an `img` tag to be able to parallax?

Comment: @Halnex, not at all, but transitioning is way faster if you animate `transform` property (which is not the case with multiple background images).